# How to filter array of object depends on input onChange text (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

(React Problem)

Let's say we have array of objects like this:

```js
    const books = [
      {
        author: "Marcel Proust",
        title: "In Search of Lost Time",
        pageNumber: 123,
      },
      {
        author: "James Joyce",
        title: "Ulysses",
        pageNumber: 123,
      },
      {
        author: "Miguel de Cervantes",
        title: "Quixote",
        pageNumber: 123,
      },
      {
        author: "Herman Melville",
        title: "Moby Dick",
        pageNumber: 123,
      },
      {
        author: "William Shakespeare",
        title: "Hamlet",
        pageNumber: 123,
      },
    ];
```

Also we have an input and state like this:

```js
    const [text, setText] = useState("");

    const handleOnChange = (event) => {
      setText(event.target.value);
    };

    <input value={text} onChange={handleOnChange} />;
```

Now, I would like to filter this array depends on input text, and [author | title] property.

Example:

If user types 'M', the array of object should look like this:

```js
    const books = [
      {
        author: "Marcel Proust",
        title: "In Search of Lost Time",
        pageNumber: 123,
      },
      {
        author: "Miguel de Cervantes",
        title: "Quixote",
        pageNumber: 123,
      },
      {
        author: "Herman Melville",
        title: "Moby Dick",
        pageNumber: 123,
      },
    ];
```

...because the author or title start with letter M.

Comment: Please show us your attempt. this isn't a free coding service. Consider reading [ask] and [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time the input text changes you can use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out the `books` where the `title` or the `author` contains the input text.

**Note**: I've used [String.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to calculate the matches but you can use other String methods as well, like [String.prototype.startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith).

```js
const books = [
  { author: "Marcel Proust", title: "In Search of Lost Time", pageNumber: 123 },
  { author: "James Joyce", title: "Ulysses", pageNumber: 123 },
  { author: "Miguel de Cervantes", title: "Quixote", pageNumber: 123 },
  { author: "Herman Melville", title: "Moby Dick", pageNumber: 123 },
  { author: "William Shakespeare", title: "Hamlet", pageNumber: 123 },
];

const App = () => {
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = React.useState("");

  const filteredBooks = books.filter(
    ({ author, title }) =>
      author.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
      title.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={searchText}
        onChange={({ target }) => setSearchText(target.value)}
      />
      <ul>
        {filteredBooks.map(({ author, title }) => (
          <li key={title}>
            <strong>{title}</strong> by {author}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this out

```js
const books = [
      {
        author: "Marcel Proust",
        title: "In Search of Lost Time",
        pageNumber: 123,
      },
      {
        author: "James Joyce",
        title: "Ulysses",
        pageNumber: 123,
      },
      {
        author: "Miguel de Cervantes",
        title: "Quixote",
        pageNumber: 123,
      },
      {
        author: "Herman Melville",
        title: "Moby Dick",
        pageNumber: 123,
      },
      {
        author: "William Shakespeare",
        title: "Hamlet",
        pageNumber: 123,
      },
    ];

const filterWithAuthorAndTitle = (books, searchParams) => {
  return books.filter(({ author, title }) => {
          const testString = `${author}${title}`.toLowerCase();
        let authorName = author.toLowerCase();
    let bookTitle = title.toLowerCase();
          return testString.includes('m') && (authorName.startsWith('m') || bookTitle.startsWith('m'));
        })
}

let filteredBooks = filterWithAuthorAndTitle(books, 'm');

console.log(filteredBooks);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
const filteredBooks = books.filter(book => {
  return book.title[0] === text || book.author[0] === text;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a filter on your `books` array.

```js
const filtered = books.filter(({author, title}) => author.includes(text) || title.includes(text)
```

This will filter with your text in ANY position on author or title. So in your example, if you type "S", you will have "William Shakespeare". If you want to search only from the begining, you can use `startsWith` instead of `includes`

Answer (score 0):

Try this filter function:

```js
books.filter(({
  author,
  title
}) => author.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase()) || title.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase()))
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this could work:

```
books.filter((book) => {
                        if (YOURINPUTVALUE === '') {
                            return book
                        } else if (
                            books.author
                                .toLowerCase()
                                .includes(YOURINPUTVALUE.toLowerCase())
                        ) {
                            return book
                        }
                    })
```